# Sorting by cell value or color in multiple cells

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I am trying to sort data based upon either color (RGB(186,200,8)) or value ("AMP") within a cell. That part is easy but the problem comes when I want to look for the same value/color in multiple columns (it can occur up to four times) and put the ones with all for equal to the value at the top and then three values next and on down to no match.

I'm not sure how to go about, I think a for loop and/or else would work but I can't come up with one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to calculate "hit" value for the row and based on that you could do the sort easily. For instance if you have two matches on the row value for that row = 2 etc. after each row validated just sort by the value and clean the data.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing, I was just hoping there was an easier way. Thanks.